# VSTS Nuget push: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: azure-artifacts

I'm attempting to push to the Package portion of VSTS.  I'm getting Bad Request back, but there's no further detail, which is very frustrating.  Here is my request and the return.

```
nuget push -Source &quot;MFS&quot; package.nupkg -Verbosity detailed -ApiKey VSTS

NuGet Version: 3.5.0.1938
Pushing package.nupkg to &#39;https://instance.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/c59817c1-a3c5-4654-95cf-760c1ce56c62/nuget/v2/&#39;...
  PUT https://instance.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/c59817c1-a3c5-4654-95cf-760c1ce56c62/nuget/v2/
  BadRequest https://instance.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/c59817c1-a3c5-4654-95cf-760c1ce56c62/nuget/v2/ 10597ms
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---&gt; System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;PushPackageToServer&gt;b__19_1(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.&lt;ProcessResponseAsync&gt;d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;PushPackageToServer&gt;d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;PushPackageCore&gt;d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;PushPackage&gt;d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;Push&gt;d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.&lt;Run&gt;d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PushCommand.&lt;ExecuteCommandAsync&gt;d__28.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
---&gt; (Inner Exception #0) System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;PushPackageToServer&gt;b__19_1(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.&lt;ProcessResponseAsync&gt;d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;PushPackageToServer&gt;d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;PushPackageCore&gt;d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;PushPackage&gt;d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.PackageUpdateResource.&lt;Push&gt;d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.PushRunner.&lt;Run&gt;d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PushCommand.&lt;ExecuteCommandAsync&gt;d__28.MoveNext()&lt;---
```

I was prompted to enter my username/password, which I assume was correct.  There is no further data than this: no output logs, no Event logs, nothing.  This is all I have to go on.

I tried removing the source and readding it, but I was not prompted to enter my credentials again, so if my credentials were somehow wrong, it's cached somewhere and I have no idea where.

TIA,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had a folder at the nupkg's root, so all my files were actually 2 levels down.  Once I brought the nuspec and other files to the root, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a `-ApiKey {string}` e.g. `-ApiKey VSTS` to push.

Comment: Quite right - sorry about that. Zach's answer below should help get you unblocked.

Comment: This was the answer for me. I just didn't realise I needed it when I am authenticating with my own creds. Odd design.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrased to satisfy StackOverflow answer policy:

We see that the package pushed was invalid because it did not contain a file ending in .nuspec. You should open the nupkg as a zip file and confirm that the package contains a file ending with .nuspec.

Comment: Hi Zach, the package does have a nuspec file.  I changed it to a .zip, unzipped and verified a nuspec file exists within the package.

Comment: Glad to see in your latest answer that you figured out the issue.
I'm currently working on enabling better error messages in NuGet 4.0 and higher, and will ensure that the error for this issue includes information about acceptable locations for the .nuspec.

Comment: That would be great.  Thanks Zach.

Comment: I also had this, in my case the Package Id wasn't set right.  Thanks to this post otherwise I'd still be pulling my hair out...

Comment: We now emit a special header with the error message. Note that only new versions (currently only the nightly, I believe) of NuGet.exe support this.  

"WARNING: The package is invalid: Can't find a .nuspec file in the package. The .nuspec file must exist within the root directory."

Please continue to give feedback like this. I know that "small" things like error messages can make a huge difference, so please speak up where we can make things better!

Comment: @ZachRenner-MSFT Error message are the BIGGEST THINGS. We need this error message as a first class citizen and prominently output. Any REST API should emit codes and a message in the HTTP response. Seriously dude. I also just ran it under Fiddler and saw nothing in the log!

Comment: Hi @LukePuplett. Are you saying that you're not seeing warnings when -ApiKey is missing, or in another scenario?  
  
For -ApiKey, if using NuGet.exe 4.3 you should actually get two warnings - one from nuget.exe itself, and another from our service, with the text 
`WARNING: The header X-NuGet-ApiKey is required when pushing a package. If using NuGet.exe, you can use -ApiKey, or the setApiKey command'.`  
That message is emitted via the header X-NUGET-WARNING. I just confirmed on a test account that the message is being emitted. Please let me know if this differs from what you see.

Comment: Also, I'm quite happy to change the error message to be more descriptive if you think it would be helpful (e.g. "you can use '-ApiKey VSTS' ... This is required for security reasons" or similar). Note that the value VSTS is unimportant and any value is acceptable - the existence of the ApiKey header itself is used as a defense against CSRF (similar to X-Requested-With) due to design decisions of the NuGet protocol. Feel free to let me know what wording makes the most sense to you, and I can promptly discuss it with my team and roll out a change.

Comment: @ZachRenner-MSFT Thanks for replying. I only saw one console warning, assumed it was from local tooling. I think a warning (advisory) for a blocking 400 is misleading. I assume there's a hard reason you can't put an error in the HTTP payload and surface that as a proper "error"? Maybe you could reword to say "...is always required when pushing a package even if you've supplied credentials." Maybe.

Comment: @LukePuplett The NuGet spec (and thus the client) only defines custom warnings: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/%5BSpec%5D-Server-side-warnings-for-NuGet-client and they're only supported on nuget.exe 4.3 and up.
I agree that it would be nice to also have errors (or maybe at least have the warnings go to stderr?) If you want to open an issue at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues I'll support you, although I expect this might be pretty low priority for the NuGet team.

Comment: @LukePuplett I've taken your suggestion and slightly tweaked it, as the message is only be shown if already authenticated: 'For security reasons, the header X-NuGet-ApiKey is always required when pushing a package even though credentials were supplied. If using NuGet.exe, you can use the -ApiKey option to set this to any value, for example "-ApiKey VSTS"'

I'll have this wording change or something very similar rolled out in our next deployment.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR always add `-ApiKey VSTS`

I eventually figured it out, too.

I omitted the `ApiKey` since I was authenticating with my credentials, so why would I need a key? And I didn't know the key for our corporate VSTS.

The warning was being shown but I was ignoring it, thinking it was a general local `NuGet.exe` warning for whenever you make it push without a key.

Then I had a brainwave that actually the warning being shown is the header value and that it somehow needs a key just for no reason other than because it does.

So with a colleague and looking at the VSTS feed instructions itself, we saw `-ApiKey VSTS` in their sample and added that and still had to login, and bingo!